How to connect SQL Server local database to node.js application
I am trying to connect a local SQL Server database to Node.js application.
I created the application using Typeorm and this is the code:
index.ts
import { AppDataSource } from "./data-source"
import { User } from "./entity/User"

AppDataSource.initialize().then(async () => {

    console.log("Inserting a new user into the database...")
    const user = new User()
    user.firstName = "Timber"
    user.lastName = "Saw"
    user.age = 25
    await AppDataSource.manager.save(user)
    console.log("Saved a new user with id: " + user.id)

    console.log("Loading users from the database...")
    const users = await AppDataSource.manager.find(User)
    console.log("Loaded users: ", users)

    console.log("Here you can setup and run express / fastify / any other framework.")

}).catch(error => console.log(error))

data-source.ts
import "reflect-metadata"
import { DataSource } from "typeorm"
import { User } from "./entity/User"

export const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
    type: "mssql",
    host: "localhost",
    username: "sa",
    password: "Admin12345",
    database: "tempdb",
    synchronize: true,
    logging: true,
    entities: [User],
    migrations: [],
    subscribers: [],
})

I get this error
ConnectionError: Failed to connect to localhost:1433 - Could not connect (sequence)
    at connectListener (E:\curated_connection\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious\connection-pool.js:85:17)
    at Connection.onConnect (E:\curated_connection\node_modules\tedious\src\connection.ts:1759:9)     
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:632:26)
    at Connection.emit (node:events:517:28)
    at Connection.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at Connection.emit (E:\curated_connection\node_modules\tedious\src\connection.ts:1902:18)
    at Connection.socketError (E:\curated_connection\node_modules\tedious\src\connection.ts:2309:12)  
    at E:\curated_connection\node_modules\tedious\src\connection.ts:2098:37
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11) {
  code: 'ESOCKET',
  originalError: ConnectionError: Failed to connect to localhost:1433 - Could not connect (sequence)  
      at Connection.socketError (E:\curated_connection\node_modules\tedious\src\connection.ts:2309:28)
      at E:\curated_connection\node_modules\tedious\src\connection.ts:2098:37
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11) {
    code: 'ESOCKET'
  }
}

I tried to connect this using Azure Data Studio and it is working well.
